# Adding Identity 2.0 Roles to custom Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2, user-roles

I recently started work on a new application using MVC 5 and Identity 2.0, in order to use a different password hashing algorithm I implemented the custom identity detailed in this guide (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-45-MVC5-Custom-1a94ab26#content).

I have looked at various ways of incorporating roles into this identity implementation but so far have not found a way of making them work with this new identity implementation.

Does anyone now of a guide on how to go about adding roles to a similar custom identity provider?

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: That tutorial is pretty worthless given that all you need to really do is implement this interface on an object and give it to the UserManager. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.ipasswordhasher%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for the advice am now using a custom password hasher implementing IPasswordHasher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your implementation of `IdentityUser` (`ApplicationUser`: if you're using the standard template) will provide the methods to associate a user with roles: `AddToRoleAsync`, `AddToRolesAsync`, `GetRolesAsync`, `RemoveFromRolesAsync`.

If you want to manage roles, as I suspect, you have to add a `RoleManager<IdentityRole>`.

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
            : base(roleStore)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var appRoleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

            return appRoleManager;
        }
    }
```

and add this to the owin context:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

The **ApplicationRoleManager** will allow you to create roles (`CreateAsync`), find (`FindByIdAsync`), delete (`DeleteAsync`).

While your **ApplicationUserManager**:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
  ...
}
```

will allow you to associate role with a user (`AddToRoleAsync`), remove (`RemoveFromRoleAsync`).

If you have implemented your **UserStore** using the interface `IUserStore`, then you need to implement `IUserRoleStore` as well.

In this last interface you can find `AddToRoleAsync`, `GetRolesAsync`, `IsInRoleAsync`, `RemoveFromRoleAsync`.

You have to implement your RoleStore (`IRoleStore`) as well.

If you want to read some good articles about this topic I would suggest you to have a look at this [blog](http://bitoftech.net/).
This guy has written 4 articles so far about **ASP.NET Identity 2.x**:

[Part 1](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/)
[Part 2](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/03/asp-net-identity-2-accounts-confirmation-password-user-policy-configuration/)
[Part 3](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/)
[Part 4](http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/11/asp-net-identity-2-1-roles-based-authorization-authentication-asp-net-web-api/) (the one you're interested in)

And this is another [guy](http://tech.trailmax.info/tag/identity/) who writes interesting stuff on the topic.