# Implementing UserManager to use a custom class and Stored Procedures

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

All of the authentication and authorization process of my app is done using stored procedures. I've written a class with all of functionalities that I need, e.g. `GetUsers`, `Login`, `AddRole`, `AddMember`, etc.
Also the admin page for managing users and roles and permissions is done by using this class.

I just need to add `authentication` (I mean that `authorize` attribute), cookies for Login and Logout and storing some server-side data for each Login. I think I need to implement `Identity` for that?

In that case, can you please guide me with its implementation? It seems the very basic thing you need to do is to implement a `create` method that passes an instance of `IUserStore` to the constructor. But I don't need to have any tables for users or roles, how can I implement this method?

This is the current class, and please let me know if you need to see my custom authentication class that uses stored procedures.

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser>
{
    public AppUserManager(IUserStore<AppUser> store) : base(store) { }
    public static AppUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<AppUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        //AppUserManager manager = new AppUserManager();
        //return manager;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [alisabzevari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692422/alisabzevari) suggested you have to implement your [IUserStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613278(v=vs.108).aspx).
You do not even depend on the storage and table structure defined. 
You can customize every single bit of your storage layer.

I did some experiments and tried to implement my own `UserManager` and `RoleManager` using a different storage, such as [Biggy](https://github.com/xivSolutions/biggy):

> A File-based Document Store for .NET.

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetIdentityCustomDb) on GitHub.

First thing to do is to implement your `UserManager` where you can configure the requirements for your password validation:

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser, int>
{
    public AppUserManager (IUserStore<AppUser, int> store): base(store)
    {
        this.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = false;
        // this.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        // this.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 10;
        this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User, int>(this)
        {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = false
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        this.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
        RequiredLength = 4,
        RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
        RequireDigit = false,
        RequireLowercase = false,
        RequireUppercase = false,
        };
    }
}
```

and then define your `IUserStore` [implementation](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetIdentityCustomDb/blob/master/Custom.Identity/UserStore.cs). The main method you must implement is `CreateAsync`:

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task CreateAsync(User user)
{
    // Saves the user in your storage.
    return Task.FromResult(user);
}
```

it will receive an `IUser` which you have to persist in your custom storage and return it.

If you have a look at the code I've [implemented](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetIdentityCustomDb/blob/master/Custom.Identity/UserStore.cs) you can see I've used a few interfaces `IUserRoleStore`, `IUserPasswordStore`, `IUserClaimStore` etc etc as I needed to use roles and claims.

I've also implemented my [own](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetIdentityCustomDb/blob/master/Custom.Identity/SignInService.cs) `SignInManager`.

Once you've defined all your implementation you can bootstrap everything at [startup](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetIdentityCustomDb/blob/master/AspNetIdentityCustomDb/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs):

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<Custom.Identity.UserManager>(() => new Custom.Identity.UserManager(new Custom.Identity.UserStore(folderStorage)));
app.CreatePerOwinContext<Custom.Identity.RoleManager>(() => new Custom.Identity.RoleManager(new Custom.Identity.RoleStore(folderStorage)));
app.CreatePerOwinContext<Custom.Identity.SignInService>((options, context) => new Custom.Identity.SignInService(context.GetUserManager<Custom.Identity.UserManager>(), context.Authentication));
```

You can check my [AccountController](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetIdentityCustomDb/blob/master/AspNetIdentityCustomDb/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L78) where I try to validate the user:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
case SignInStatus.Success:
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
    return View("Lockout");
case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
case SignInStatus.Failure:
default:
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Once `PasswordSignInAsync` is called you will notice a few of the methods of your `UserManager` will be called. The first one will be [FindByNameAsync](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetIdentityCustomDb/blob/master/Custom.Identity/UserStore.cs#L63):

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    //Fetch your user using the username.
    return Task.FromResult(user);
}
```

You will have to implement your stored procedure, I guess, where you'll fetch your user from the DB.

Then another method `FindByIdAsync` will be [called](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetIdentityCustomDb/blob/master/Custom.Identity/UserStore.cs#L49):

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<User> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
{
    // Fetch - again - your user from the DB with the Id.
    return Task.FromResult(user);
}
```

Again you'll have to use your stored procedure to find your user by his/her id.

If you download my project from github and play around with it you'll notice that most of those methods will be called multiple times. Don't get scared. That's the way it is.

I would suggest you to insert breakpoints in every single method of the [UserStore](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetIdentityCustomDb/blob/master/Custom.Identity/UserStore.cs) and see how everything fits together.

Comment: `The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.` For login and in the `UserManager.FindAsync` I get the above error. Any idea? I think it's relative to `GetPasswordHashAsync`.What can I do for that?

Comment: It's hard to tell. Did you try my sample project? FindAsync uses UserLoginInfo. It goes through that pipe if you're using an external provider (google, facebook). If you don't use that you should go through there. In case you're using an external provider you can implement the UserLoginInfo manager. You can check Raven's [implementation](https://github.com/ILMServices/RavenDB.AspNet.Identity/blob/master/RavenDB.AspNet.Identity/UserStore.cs#L134).

Comment: Thanks Lefty, I've checked your code. I'm not using external providers. And instead of using User manager's Find, I've used my own custom function to save some time! :)

Comment: @Akbari: Glad I've helped. If you think my answer is good enough, could you, please, accept it? Cheers.

Comment: I have downloaded the project from the link you have given in your answer but i am stuck here :app.CreatePerOwinContext<Custom.Identity.UserManager>(() => new Custom.Identity.UserManager(new Custom.Identity.UserStore(folderStorage)));
app.CreatePerOwinContext<Custom.Identity.RoleManager>(() => new Custom.Identity.RoleManager(new Custom.Identity.RoleStore(folderStorage)));

Comment: I want to store directly in my table.can you please guide me a little.please

Comment: @Learning: Maybe you should provide us with some more details? The implementation here is for a custom IUserStore. Maybe you don't need one.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304464/how-to-save-new-record-with-hashed-password-in-my-custom-table-instead-of-aspnet

Comment: Thank you a lot! This was very clarifying! You're awesome!!!!

Answer (score 5):

You have to implement IUserStore interface. See [this article](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) to learn how to implement Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 3):

You can also override methods in your `UserManager` class (e.g. `ApplicationUserManager`) to manage authorization. Here is an example that uses custom `UserManager.FindAsync` logic. The `UserManager` class is used by the `ApplicationOAuthProvider` class during authentication.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager() : base(new EmptyUserStore()) { }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationUserManager();
    }

    public override Task<ApplicationUser> FindAsync(string userName, string password)
    {
        // Authentication logic here.
        throw new NotImplementedException("Authenticate userName and password");

        var result = new ApplicationUser { UserName = userName };
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// User Store with no implementation. Required for UserManager.
/// </summary>
internal class EmptyUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation does not use the benefits of the `IUserStore` interface.