# Increase token lifespan in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity, .net-core-3.1

How to configure the `TokenLifespan` of a token generated in .NET Core 3.1? I am using the following code but it's not working and is still using the 1-day `TokenLifespan` which is the default value.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    //...
    services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
    });
    //...
}
```

I am not interested in configuration through custom classes when there is a builtin option to change it through the code given above but I don't know what am I doing wrong which is overriding my defined `TokenLifeSpan` value.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: As far as the solution to override the default expiry time is concerned then no I did not find the solution. But I added a feature of regenerating the token and allowed users to generate again when required.

Comment: I was looking how to do this on .NET 5 and your question was my answer. It works for me no problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a provider that is based on TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider i.e. EmailTokenProvider or PhoneNumberTokenProvider, then I don't think this is possible.

The Totp provider produces 6 digit codes, and has a life span of 3 minutes with a 90 seconds variance.

You would probably have to find a way to create your own OTP if you require them to be longer.

**EDIT**

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712760/asp-identity-2-change-expiry-time-for-mobile-token) post on how you can override the Rfc6238AuthenticationService to the extended/decrease your token lifespan

Comment: According to the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/b7826741279450c58b230ece98bd04b4815beabf/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs#L82) the variance is actually 9 mins.

Answer (score 0):

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?hubRefSrc=email&utm_source=lfemail&utm_medium=email&tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-3.1#change-the-email-token-lifespan) shows how to change the email token lifespan, you need to add a custom `DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>` and `DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions`.

The same on github issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/5436#issuecomment-373965907

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated my question. In both links you shared, the same answer is given for extending lifespan overall which I am using but it's not working for me, and still using the default value of 1 day.