# .net core identity server Custom token provider generating long token string

Tags: asp.net-core, token, identity

This is how I configured my custom token provider,

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider",
                            new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>)));
                options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider";
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>()
                .AddTokenProvider<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>("CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider");
```

And this is code for custom token provider class,

```
 public class CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser> : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
    {
        public CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,IOptions<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions> options
            , ILogger<DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>> logger)
            : base(dataProtectionProvider, options,logger)
        { }
    }
    public class CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
    {
        public CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions()
        {
            Name = "CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider";
            TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        }
    }
```

this is how I generate user token,

```
var myToken = await usrManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider", UserManager<object>.ResetPasswordTokenPurpose);
```

and this is how I verify the token validity using custom provider,

```
 var isValid = await usrManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(userinfo, "CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider", 
                                   UserManager<object>.ResetPasswordTokenPurpose, model.Token);
```

The above codes,including setting of TokenLifeSpan are working fine.
But the token is generating as a long string as example below,

> CfDJ8IvIvIomoPJKkcJtJSNCN4wB6Fp82OPzYvkVaHtBzJBjY9EwOBt2nMg1WudWBTc1giurpRIXhSHeJTe3CLswJEOL7nng9Hd7H/ctDVNSEL5eBnzXVZpvSNmVCvgwIg3cwSNtcjjsYmGFA01EgyEkXXkBZg+jLDiEsKU8YgmaoQd5bOLE3WLopZo2lboG7dOnZv777SMHitbQNJ2SdRyZf2aMAybKAkHnKGIR3ZSyQXRM

I want to change this toke as just **6 digits** characters.
Where should I modify to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you mean you generate 6 digit character token for the identity provider?

Comment: @BrandoZhang , Yes, I want to generate 6 digit token, I can generate by DefaultTokenProvider, but unfortunately, DefaultTokenProvider cannot change time out period. The reason why I use customToken provider is to use 6 digit code token and change time span from this token.

Comment: The actual token being generated by asp.net is only 6-digits. It's the data protection provider that encrypts it to this long string. You can debug the original source to check this behaviour. If you need only 6-digit tokens, look at phone tokens

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the asp.net sources, you will see that the default token provider is inherited from the TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider [DefaultEmailTokenProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/EmailTokenProvider.cs) which uses the "D6" format in the GenerateAsync method [TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider.cs) whereas your custom provider is inherited from the DataProtectorTokenProvider which uses the Base64String format in the GenerateAsync method [DataProtectorTokenProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/DataProtectorTokenProvider.cs). I think you can try to change the base class for your custom provider to get a 6 digits token, but the Rfc6238AuthenticationService that is used by the TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider has a hardcoded lifespan of 3 minutes [Rfc6238AuthenticationService](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs). For creating a custom Rfc6238AuthenticationService see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712760/asp-identity-2-change-expiry-time-for-mobile-token).

**CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider**

```cs
    public class CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser> : TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
    {
        private readonly TimeSpan _timeStep;

        public CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider()
        {
            // Here you can setup expiration time.
            _timeStep = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        }

        public override async Task<string> GenerateAsync(
          string purpose,
          UserManager<TUser> manager,
          TUser user)
        {
            if (manager == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(manager));
            byte[] token = await manager.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(user);
            string async = CustomRfc6238AuthenticationService.GenerateCode
                (
                    token,
                    await this.GetUserModifierAsync(purpose, manager, user),
                    _timeStep
                )
                .ToString("D6", (IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            token = (byte[])null;
            return async;
        }
        
        public override async Task<bool> ValidateAsync(
          string purpose,
          string token,
          UserManager<TUser> manager,
          TUser user)
        {
            if (manager == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(manager));
            int code;
            if (!int.TryParse(token, out code))
                return false;
            byte[] securityToken = await manager.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(user);
            string userModifierAsync = await this.GetUserModifierAsync(purpose, manager, user);
            return securityToken != null && CustomRfc6238AuthenticationService.ValidateCode(
                securityToken,
                code,
                userModifierAsync,
                _timeStep);
        }
        
        // It's just a dummy for inheritance.
        public override Task<bool> CanGenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
```

**CustomRfc6238AuthenticationService**

```cs
    public static class CustomRfc6238AuthenticationService
    {
        private static readonly TimeSpan _timestep = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
        private static readonly Encoding _encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);

        internal static int ComputeTotp(
        HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm,
            ulong timestepNumber,
            byte[]? modifierBytes)
        {
            // # of 0's = length of pin
            const int Mod = 1000000;

            // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4226
            // We can add an optional modifier
            var timestepAsBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((long)timestepNumber));
            var hash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(ApplyModifier(timestepAsBytes, modifierBytes));

            // Generate DT string
            var offset = hash[hash.Length - 1] & 0xf;
            Debug.Assert(offset + 4 < hash.Length);
            var binaryCode = (hash[offset] & 0x7f) << 24
                                | (hash[offset + 1] & 0xff) << 16
                                | (hash[offset + 2] & 0xff) << 8
                                | (hash[offset + 3] & 0xff);

            return binaryCode % Mod;
        }

        private static byte[] ApplyModifier(Span<byte> input, byte[] modifierBytes)
        {
            var combined = new byte[checked(input.Length + modifierBytes.Length)];
            input.CopyTo(combined);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(modifierBytes, 0, combined, input.Length, modifierBytes.Length);

            return combined;
        }

        // More info: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238#section-4
        private static ulong GetCurrentTimeStepNumber(TimeSpan timeStep)
        {
            var delta = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow - DateTimeOffset.UnixEpoch;

            return (ulong)(delta.Ticks / timeStep.Ticks);
        }
        
        public static int GenerateCode(byte[] securityToken, string? modifier = null, TimeSpan? timeStep = null)
        {
            if (securityToken == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(securityToken));
            }

            // Allow a variance of no greater than time step in either direction
            var currentTimeStep = GetCurrentTimeStepNumber(timeStep ?? _timestep);

            var modifierBytes = modifier is not null ? _encoding.GetBytes(modifier) : null;
            
            using (var hashAlgorithm = new HMACSHA1(securityToken))
            {
                return ComputeTotp(hashAlgorithm, currentTimeStep, modifierBytes);
            }
        }

        public static bool ValidateCode(byte[] securityToken, int code, string? modifier = null, TimeSpan? timeStep = null)
        {
            if (securityToken == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(securityToken));
            }

            // Allow a variance of no greater than time step in either direction
            var currentTimeStep = GetCurrentTimeStepNumber(timeStep ?? _timestep);
            
            using (var hashAlgorithm = new HMACSHA1(securityToken))
            {
                var modifierBytes = modifier is not null ? _encoding.GetBytes(modifier) : null;
                for (var i = -2; i <= 2; i++)
                {
                    var computedTotp = ComputeTotp(hashAlgorithm, (ulong)((long)currentTimeStep - i), modifierBytes);
                    if (computedTotp == code)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            // No match
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```cs
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
if (user != null)
{
    var token = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider", UserManager<object>.ResetPasswordTokenPurpose);

    var isValid = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, "CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider", UserManager<object>.ResetPasswordTokenPurpose, token);
}
```

*Note*: This algorithm has a variance of no greater than time step in either direction.

Comment: would you show me with some example codes ?